# when do classes in jars enter the PermGen

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, classloader, permgen

My understanding is that the PermGen (in some sense) holds the class code in memory. Often we have lots of jar files referenced our classpath. When a jar file is included in the classpath (say in the lib directory of tomcat), are all the classes of all those jars automatically loaded into the PermGen?

In a similar question, once a class of a jar file is used, does PermGen load all the classes in that jar file, or just the class that is used (and then later load the rest of the class files when necessary)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends to some degree on the implementation of the classloader and the JVM - the [Java Virtual Machine specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2) says this:

> This specification allows an implementation flexibility as to when
>   linking activities (and, because of recursion, loading) take place,
>   provided that the semantics of the Java programming language are
>   respected, [...]
>
> For example, an implementation may choose to resolve each symbolic
>   reference in a class or interface individually, only when it is used
>   (lazy or late resolution), or to resolve them all at once while the
>   class is being verified (static resolution). This means that the
>   resolution process may continue, in some implementations, after a
>   class or interface has been initialized.

In practice, no sane implementation should automatically load everything in a JAR file just because one class in the file is loaded, let alone just because it's on the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

PermGen is an implementation detail of HotSpot and Oracle said they want to get rid of it in the future [1]. It is in no part of the Java (VM) specification. Only loaded classes end up in PermGen. Either explicitly trough `ClassLoader#loadClass` or implicitly through linking. That should only be the used classes (and their dependencies) unless somebody is explicitly loading all classes eg. to perform reflection on them. Frameworks like Spring avoid this and instead scan the byte code.

A good staring point is [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) that allows you to observe loaded classes an PermGen.

[1] JRockit does not have PermGen and in recent HotSpot versions the string intern pool is no longer in PermGen.

Comment: It's worth noting that only java.lang.Class objects, some of the java.lang.String objects associated with the class's name and method names, and static objects referred to by the Class will be loaded into PermGen. It's not like your bytecode gets loaded in there or anything...

Answer (score 0):

Only needed classes are loaded and stored in the permgen space.

Answer (score 0):

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) guarantees that a class is initialized when -- and no sooner than -- it is first required. The implementation is allowed to perform loading and linking earlier, though.

Comment: Actually the spec explicitly allows pre-loading classes. That a class has to be loaded before it is used is pretty obvious.

Comment: And what about initializing them?

Comment: That's a different matter. I don't think initialization is relevant to PermGen usage, though I suppose an implementation might delay loading related classes until initialization.